# Adonis.js api Sign Up route is not working

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have an Adonis.js api-only app and my auth routes are not working.

Here is my signup route:

```
const Route = use('Route')

...

Route.post('/signup', 'UserController.signup')
```

Here is the action in the UserController:

```
'use strict'

const User = use('App/Models/User')
const Hash = use('Hash')
const Writ = use('App/Models/Writ')

class UserController {

  async signup ({ request, auth, response }) {
      // get user data from signup form
      const userData = request.only(['name', 'username', 'email', 'password'])
      console.log(userData);

      try {
          // save user to database
          const user = await User.create(userData)
          console.log(user);
          // generate JWT token for user
          const token = await auth.generate(user)

          return response.json({
              status: 'success',
              data: token
          })
      } catch (error) {
          return response.status(400).json({
              status: 'error',
              message: 'There was a problem creating the user, please try again later.'
          })
      }
  }
...

module.exports = UserController
```

Using Postman, the console prints the request but returns:

{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "There was a problem creating the user, please try again later."
}

Comment: can you put whats error generate in a catch block? console error in a catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it:

```
'use strict'
const User = use('App/Models/User')
const Hash = use('Hash')
class UserController {
    async signup ({ request, auth, response }) {
      // get user data from signup form
      const userData = request.only(['username', 'email', 'password']) 
      // ! Only existing fields in the database 

      console.log(userData);

      try {
        // save user to databas
        const user = new User()
        user.fill(userData)
        await user.save()

        // generate JWT token for user
        const token = await auth.generate(user)
        return response.json({
            status: 'success',
            data: token
        })
      } catch (error) {
          return response.status(400).json({
              status: 'error',
              message: error
          })
      }
    }
}

module.exports = UserController
```

It would be interesting to add a try/catch when creating the user to better target errors.

*If it doesn't work, check the configuration files.*

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you put all configuration right as mention in [this](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/authentication) document.

- if your config right then this issue is **user** migration issue.
- because user migration don't content **name** field so first check without send **name** into postman and not get **name** in controller like this

  ```
  'use strict'

  const User = use('App/Models/User')
  const Hash = use('Hash')
  const Writ = use('App/Models/Writ')

  class UserController {

      async signup ({ request, auth, response }) {

           const userData =request.only(['username','email','password'])
           console.log(userData);

           try {

                const user = await User.create(userData)
                console.log(user);
                // generate JWT token for user
                const token = await auth.generate(user)

               return response.json({
                      status: 'success',
                      data: token
               })
            } catch (error) {
                      return response.status(400).json({
                             status: 'error',
                             message: error
                       })
       }
    }
    ...

   module.exports = UserController
  ```

and then try to  generate token it's work

- if you get success in response then change migration of user